# Approximate indoor positioning using the integration of the linear acceleration

Tags: android, location, android-sensors, indoor-positioning-system

I am trying to calculate the approximate position of an Android phone in a room. I tried with different methods such as location (wich is terrible in indoors) and gyroscope+compass. I only need to know the approximate position after walking during 5-10seconds so I think the integration of linear acceleration could be enough. I know the error is terrible because of the propagation of the error but maybe it will work in my setup. I only need the approximate position to point a camera to the Android phone.

I coded the double integration but I am doing sth wrong. IF the phone is static on a table the position (x,y,z) always keep increasing. What is the problem?

```
 static final float NS2S = 1.0f / 1000000000.0f;
    float[] last_values = null;
    float[] velocity = null;
    float[] position = null;
    float[] acceleration = null;
    long last_timestamp = 0;
    SensorManager mSensorManager;
    Sensor mAccelerometer;

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
         if (event.sensor.getType() != Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION)
             return;

         if(last_values != null){
                float dt = (event.timestamp - last_timestamp) * NS2S;

                acceleration[0]=(float) event.values[0] - (float) 0.0188;
                acceleration[1]=(float) event.values[1] - (float) 0.00217;
                acceleration[2]=(float) event.values[2] + (float) 0.01857;

                for(int index = 0; index < 3;++index){
                    velocity[index] += (acceleration[index] + last_values[index])/2 * dt;
                    position[index] += velocity[index] * dt;
                }
            }
            else{
                last_values = new float[3];
                acceleration = new float[3];
                velocity = new float[3];
                position = new float[3];
                velocity[0] = velocity[1] = velocity[2] = 0f;
                position[0] = position[1] = position[2] = 0f;
            }
            System.arraycopy(acceleration, 0, last_values, 0, 3);
            last_timestamp = event.timestamp;
    }
```

These are the positions I get when the phone is on the table (no motion). The (x,y,z) values are increasing but the phone is still. [image]

And these are the positions after calculate the moving average for each axis and substract from each measurement. The phone is also still.
[image]

How to improve the code or another method to get the approximate position inside a room?

Answer (score 4):

There are unavoidable measurement errors in the accelerometer. These are caused by tiny vibrations in the table, imperfections in the manufacturing, etc. etc. Accumulating these errors over time results in a [Random Walk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk). This is why positioning systems can only use accelerometers as a positioning aid through some filter. They still require some form of dead reckoning such as GPS (which doesn't work well in doors).

There is a great deal of current research for indoor positioning systems. Some areas of research into systems that can take advantage of existing infrastructure are WiFi and LED lighting positioning. There is no obvious solution yet, but I'm sure we'll need a dedicated solution for accurate, reliable indoor positioning.

You said the position always keeps increasing. Do you mean the x, y, and z components only ever become positive, even after resetting several times? Or do you mean the position keeps drifting from zero?

If you output the raw acceleration measurements when the phone is still you should see the measurement errors. Put a bunch of these measurements in an Excel spreadsheet. Calculate the mean and the standard deviation. The mean should be zero for all axes. If not there is a bias that you can remove in your code with a simple averaging filter (calculate a running average and subtract that from each result). The standard deviation will show you how far you can expect to drift in each axis after N time steps as standard_deviation * sqrt(N). This should help you mathematically determine the expected accuracy as a function of time (or N time steps).

Comment: The position always keeps increasing.  I plotted the measrements on Matlab and the  mean is not zero. It seems there is a bias that keeps increasing the values for each position. I can try to remove it with an average filter but I am wondering if the bias is due to an error on my code or the accumulative error. Do you have any good reference about positioning based on acceleration and/or filtering (average filter or other types)?

Comment: If you are printing the output of event.values[index], how can it be your code that is causing the bias? Also a bias is normal in raw accelerometer measurements. I can't think of any reference that won't overwhelm you with detail that you don't need. Let's assume the bias is fixed throughout the life of your application, but differs from handset to handset. Just calculate the [moving average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average) of each axis and subtract that from the measurement.

Comment: If you are concerned that the bias will change throughout the life of a single run of your application you can use an [exponential moving average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Exponential_moving_average). Choose an alpha between 0 and 1. Larger values of alpha mean your filter will adjust more quickly to changes in the mean, but be more susceptible to noise. Maybe you can play around with some plots in matlab. If you are really interested in filter theory I'd start with Understanding Digital Signal Processing, Lyons.

Comment: I calculate the moving average on Matlab (using the moving average filter) and substracted from the measurements. The problem is the same so I guess I am doing some mistake on the code, maybe when I calculate the position through the double integration? I edited the question adding the values I get when the phone is still on a table. before and after substracting the moving average from each axis.

Comment: Can you update your code to show how you are calculating the moving average and subtracting it? You should be calculating three moving averages of each event.values[index], and subtracting that average from each event.values[index]. You should not be averaging the position.

Comment: I calculated the moving average using the moving average filter on Matlab. Then I subtracted from each axis. Code is uploaded now.

Comment: nabrugir, did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 2):

Brian is right, there are already deployed indoor positioning systems that work with infrastructure that you can easily find in (almost) any room.
One of the solutions that has proven to be most reliable is WiFi fingerprinting. I recommend you take a look at indoo.rs - www.indoo.rs - they are pioneers in the industry and have a pretty developed system already.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most elegant or reliable solution, but in my case it serves the purpose.

**Note** In my case, I am grabbing a location before the user can even enter the activity that needs indoor positioning.. and I am only concerned with a rough estimate of how much they have moved around.

I have a sensor manager that is creating a rotation matrix based on the device orientation. (using `Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR`)  That obviously doesn't give me movement forward, backward, or side to side, but instead only the device orientation.  With that device orientation i have a good idea of the user's bearing in degrees (which way they are facing) and using the `Sensor_Step_Detector` available in KitKat 4.4, I make the assumption that a step is 1 meter in the direction the user is facing..

Again, I know this is not full proof or very accurate, but depending on your purpose this too might be a simple solution..

everytime a step is detected i basically call this function:

```
public void computeNewLocationByStep() {
       Location newLocal = new Location("");
       double vAngle = getBearingInDegrees(); // returns my users bearing
       double vDistance = 1 / g.kEarthRadiusInMeters; //kEarthRadiusInMeters =  6353000;
        vAngle = Math.toRadians(vAngle);

        double vLat1 = Math.toRadians(_location.getLatitude());
        double vLng1 = Math.toRadians(_location.getLongitude());

        double vNewLat = Math.asin(Math.sin(vLat1) * Math.cos(vDistance) +
                      Math.cos(vLat1) * Math.sin(vDistance) * Math.cos(vAngle));

        double vNewLng = vLng1 + Math.atan2(Math.sin(vAngle) * Math.sin(vDistance) * Math.cos(vLat1),
                              Math.cos(vDistance) - Math.sin(vLat1) * Math.sin(vNewLat));



        newLocal.setLatitude(Math.toDegrees(vNewLat));
        newLocal.setLongitude(Math.toDegrees(vNewLng));

        stepCount =0;
        _location = newLocal;

    }
```